# Creating a list within a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list named values containing a series of numbers:

```
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , 351, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... , 750, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , 559]
```

I want to create a new list that contains a list of elements from 0 up to a number.

Like :

```
new_values = [[0, 1, 2, ... , 351], [0, 1, 2, ... , 750], [0, 1, 2, ... , 559]]
```

The code that I did was this:

```
start = 0
new_values = []
for i,val in enumerate(values): 
    if(val == 0):
        new_values.append(values[start:i]) 
        start = i
```

However, what it returns this:

```
new_values = [[], [0, 1, 2, ... , 750], [0, 1, 2, ... , 559]]
```

How can I fix my code? It will really be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your elements with `itertools.groupby` based on the presence of `0` (which is falsy) and extract the sublists between `0` while appending the missing `0` with a list comprehension:

```
 [[0]+list(g) for k, g in groupby(values, bool) if k]
```

Example:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 351, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 559]
>>> [[0]+list(g) for k, g in groupby(values, bool) if k]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 559]]
```

Comment: Minor note: This assumes `0`s never occur back-to-back, and `values` always starts with `0`. The OP's example follows this rule, so if that rule is guaranteed, this is by far the simplest/most performant solution.

Comment: Correction: [It's actually quite slow as written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909193/364696) because `bool` has absurd overhead. Replacing `bool` with `operator.truth` as the `key` function will remove that overhead, making this similar cost to other optimized solutions (slightly slower, but trivially so, where `bool` can make it take 3x what the optimized non-`groupby` solutions require). Personally, if performance isn't critical, I'd use this solution as is; if performance is critical, swapping to `operator.truth` would get you a major speedup with minimal complexity change.

Comment: @ShadowRanger How interesting, already upvoted your solution but did not know about these nuances, thanks for sharing! Are you saying that in general `operator.truth` is preferable to `bool` for performance?  It seems odd that the standard library includes 2 equivalent functions like this (although `bool()` does not require an argument like `truth`)

Comment: Yeah, I knew `bool` was slower than it should be, didn't realize just how much slower until I tested it head-to-head against `operator.truth`. The problem is that CPython built-in constructors have to use a fairly general dispatch mechanism supporting variable length positional and keyword arguments. The interpreter builds `tuple` and `dict`, then `bool`'s `tp_new` calls `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` (for some dumb reason they allowed you to actually use a keyword argument for `bool`, which means they need to check for them every time); that's only the basics of constructor bookkeeping.

Comment: By contrast, `operator.truth` is of a specially optimized class of plain functions (it has the argument type flag `METH_O` which means it takes exactly one positional argument, no more, no less, no keyword args, where `tp_new` is always `METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS`). Being a plain function, no constructor specific machinery is invoked; being `METH_O`, no `tuple` or `dict` must be created and subsequently unpacked. Ultimately, the work they both do is `PyBool_FromLong(PyObject_IsTrue(argval))`, but it's buried under a ton of kruft in the `bool` constructor.

Comment: Oh, and hey, apparently the CPython folks decided some of these decisions should be fixed; [as of 3.7, `bool` no longer attempts to use keyword arguments](https://bugs.python.org/issue29695), it just complains if any are passed and uses `PyArg_UnpackTuple` to unpack the `tuple` without having format strings to parse, so it should run faster. Don't have a copy of 3.7 to test with, but it's something.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you! Yah the differences are super striking `%timeit [bool(x) for x in range(1000000)]` >>> `141 ms` and `%timeit [truth(x) for x in range(1000000)]` >>> `69.6 ms`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Would you like to write this up as a seperate Q&A? "What are the differences between bool() and operator.truth()?" I think the community would really appreciate that! You could also mention the keywords point more generally, is is bizarre that `bool(x=1)` and `int(x=1)` are valid, I see zero use cases

Comment: @ShadowRanger Would you mind if I wrote a short Q&A if you're not going too? I'll cite you and this post of course

Comment: Feel free to write one up. I wouldn't point out the keyword "feature" personally, since it's going to go away, but simply noting that it uses more general argument parsing (a necessary consequence of being a type constructor rather than a function) is both true and will remain true even in 3.7 (it'll be more efficient, but still have to do more work for argument parsing even then).

Comment: BTW, the same basic performance pattern is seen with `int` vs. `operator.index` (though in that case, there are differences in behavior as well; `index` requires `int`-like inputs, where `int` is willing to coerce strings and non-integer numeric types).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ok thank you! Just posted a Q&A. I also did some timings on the latest Python 3.8 branch via wandbox and found that bool() is still a lot slower than truth(), presumably due to the generic implementation of bool as you say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009870/what-are-the-differences-between-bool-and-operator-truth/

Answer (score 5):

So your problem with the code as written is that it includes an empty `list` at the beginning, and omits the final sub-`list`. The minimalist fix for this is:

1. Change the test to avoid appending the first `list` (when `i` is 0), e.g. `if val == 0 and i != 0:`
2. Append the final group after the loop exits

Combining the two fixes, you'd have:

```
start = 0
new_values = []
for i,val in enumerate(values): 
    if val == 0 and i != 0:  # Avoid adding empty list
        new_values.append(values[start:i]) 
        start = i
if values:  # Handle edgecase for empty values where nothing to add
    new_values.append(values[start:])  # Add final list
```

I was going to add the cleaner `groupby` solution which avoids the special cases for beginning/end of `list`, but [Chris_Rands already handled that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909138/364696), so I'll refer you to his answer.

Somewhat surprisingly, this actually seems to be the fastest solution, asymptotically, at the expense of requiring the input to be a `list` (where some of the other solutions can accept arbitrary iterables, including pure iterators for which indexing is impossible).

For comparison (using Python 3.5 additional unpacking generalizations both for brevity and to get optimal performance on modern Python, and using the implicit booleanness of `int` to avoid comparing to `0` since it's equivalent for `int` input, but meaningfully faster to use implicit booleanness):

```
from itertools import *

# truth is the same as bool, but unlike the bool constructor, it requires
# exactly one positional argument, which makes a *major* difference
# on runtime when it's in a hot code path
from operator import truth

def method1(values):
    # Optimized/correct OP's code
    # Only works on list inputs, and requires non-empty values to begin with 0,
    # but handles repeated 0s as separate groups properly
    new_values = []
    start = None
    for i, val in enumerate(values):
        if not val and i:
            new_values.append(values[start:i])
            start = i
    if values:
        new_values.append(values[start:])
    return new_values

def method2(values):
    # Works with arbitrary iterables and iterators, but doesn't handle
    # repeated 0s or non-empty values that don't begin with 0
    return [[0, *g] for k, g in groupby(values, truth) if k]

def method3(values):
    # Same behaviors and limitations as method1, but without verbose
    # special casing for begin and end
    start_indices = [i for i, val in enumerate(values) if not val]

    # End indices for all but terminal slice are previous start index
    # so make iterator and discard first value to pair properly
    end_indices = iter(start_indices)
    next(end_indices, None)

    # Pairing with zip_longest avoids need to explicitly pad end_indices
    return [values[s:e] for s, e in zip_longest(start_indices, end_indices)]

def method4(values):
    # Requires any non-empty values to begin with 0
    # but otherwise handles runs of 0s and arbitrary iterables (including iterators)
    new_values = []
    for val in values:
        if not val:
            curlist = [val]
            new_values.append(curlist)
            # Use pre-bound method in local name for speed
            curlist_append = curlist.append
        else:
            curlist_append(val)
    return new_values

def method5(values):
    # Most flexible solution; similar to method2, but handles all inputs, empty, non-empty,
    # with or without leading 0, with or without runs of repeated 0s
    new_values = []
    for nonzero, grp in groupby(values, truth):
        if nonzero:
            try:
                new_values[-1] += grp
            except IndexError:
                new_values.append([*grp])  # Only happens when values begins with nonzero
        else:
            new_values += [[0] for _ in grp]
    return new_values
```

Timings on Python 3.6, Linux x64, using `ipython` 6.1's `%timeit` magic:

```
>>> values = [*range(100), *range(50), *range(150)]
>>> %timeit -r5 method1(values)
12.5 μs ± 50.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit -r5 method2(values)
16.9 μs ± 54.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit -r5 method3(values)
13 μs ± 18.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit -r5 method4(values)
16.7 μs ± 9.51 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit -r5 method5(values)
18.2 μs ± 25.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Summary:**

**Solutions that slice out the runs in bulk** (`method1`, `method3`) **are the fastest**, but depend on the input being a sequence (and if the return type must be `list`, the input must be `list` too, or conversions must be added).

**`groupby` solutions** (`method2`, `method5`) **are a little slower, but are typically quite succinct** (handling all edges cases as in `method5` doesn't require extreme verbosity nor explicit test-and-check LBYL patterns). **They also don't require a lot of hackery to make them go as fast as possible**, aside from using `operator.truth` instead of `bool`. This is necessary because CPython's `bool` constructor is *very* slow thanks to some weird implementation details (`bool` must accept full varargs, including keywords, dispatching through the object construction machinery, which costs a lot more than `operator.truth` which uses a low overhead path that takes exactly one positional argument and bypasses object construction machinery); if `bool` were used as the `key` function instead of `operator.truth`, runtimes more than double (to 36.8 μs and 38.8 μs for `method2` and `method5` respectively).

In between is the **slower, but more flexible approach** (handles arbitrary input iterables, including iterators, handles runs of 0s with no special casing, etc.) **using item-by-item `append`s** (`method4`). Problem is, **getting maximum performance requires much more verbose code** (because of the need to avoid repeated indexing and method binding); if the loop of `method4` is changed to the much more succinct:

```
for val in values:
    if not val:
        new_values.append([])
    new_values[-1].append(val)
```

the runtime more than doubles (to ~34.4 μs), thanks to the cost of repeatedly indexing `new_values` and binding the `append` method over and over.

In any event, personally, **if performance wasn't absolutely critical, I'd use one of the `groupby` solutions using `bool` as the `key`** just to avoid imports and uncommon APIs. **If performance was more important, I'd probably still use `groupby`, but swap in `operator.truth` as the `key` function**; sure, it's not as fast as the spelled out version, but for people who know `groupby`, it's easy enough to follow, and it's generally the most succinct solution for any given level of edge case handling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` by finding all groups where each value is less than the element that proceeds it in `values`:

```
import itertools
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 559]
new_vals = [[i[-1] for i in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(enumerate(values), key=lambda x:x[-1] <= values[x[0]+1] if x[0]+1 < len(values) else False)]
final_data = [new_vals[i]+new_vals[i+1] for i in range(0, len(new_vals), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 559]]
```

Comment: Using `map` when you need a `list` anyway, and rely on a `lambda` to do so, is just slower/more verbose than the equivalent listcomp. And as long as you definitely consume the group before requesting the next, you needn't listify the group up front. You could replace `list(map(lambda x:x[-1], list(b)))` with `[x[-1] for x in b]` and it would behave identically (except faster, and easier to read). If you really love `map`, importing `itemgetter` from `operator` and doing `list(map(itemgetter(-1), b))` would at least avoid the speed hit, but I'd usually stick with the listcomp.

Comment: @ShadowRanger List comprehension is certainly better than `map`. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 559]
new_values = []

split_at = 0  # split the list when this value is reached

idx = -1
for value in values:
    if value == split_at:
        idx += 1
        new_values.append([])

    new_values[idx].append(value)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 559]]
```

It also handles edgecasses.

My method is a bit faster than [Chris_Rands's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909138/4797683), but it's also a bit slower than [Vasilis G's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48910200/4797683) method:

```
from itertools import groupby


values = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 559,
]


def method1():
    new_values = []

    idx = -1
    for value in values:
        if value == 0:
            idx += 1
            new_values.append([])

        new_values[idx].append(value)

    return new_values


def method2():
    new_values = [[0] + list(g) for k, g in groupby(values, bool) if k]
    return new_values


def method3():
    indices = [index for index, value in enumerate(values) if value == 0] + [len(values)]
    new_values = [values[indices[i]:indices[i + 1]] for i in range(len(indices) - 1)]
    return new_values
```

---

```
>>> timeit.timeit(method1, number=100000)
0.6725746986698414
>>> timeit.timeit(method2, number=100000)
0.8143814620314903
>>> timeit.timeit(method3, number=100000)
0.6596001360341748
```

Comment: You can save some work by avoiding the use of `idx` entirely; you always want to append to the final `list` in `new_values`, so just use negative indexing, `new_values[-1].append(...)`, rather than maintaining `idx` and doing `new_values[idx].append(...)`.

Comment: Alternatively, for even faster performance, in your `if` case you do: `new_values.append([])`, `add_to_cur_list = new_values[-1].append`, then change the code outside the `if` to `add_to_cur_list(value)`, so you avoid the indexing and method binding overhead in common case entirely.

Comment: Also, a note on performance: When the runs to be grouped get long, [my minimalist change to the OP's original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909193/364696) actually seems to be the fastest (with your `method3` code being a close second, though there is room for a little improvement on it, speedwise, specifically, changing `[values[indices[i]:indices[i + 1]] for i in range(len(indices) - 1)]` to `[values[s:e] for s, e in zip(indices, indices[1:])]` to remove two explicit index lookups and an addition per item). Try it with 0-based groups that are each ~100 items long to see.

Comment: Huh. One last note: I just wrote up a more comprehensive set of performance comparisons for larger groups (which gives a better idea of how the solutions scale, avoiding penalizing a method for moderate fixed setup costs if the method is faster per-item). Most surprising discovery was just how much using `bool` as the `key` function slows you down; using `operator.truth` (does the exact same job as `bool` in this use case) halves runtime by avoiding the expense associated w/object construction machinery (that ultimately doesn't even construct anything, since `True`/`False` are singletons).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 559]

# Find all indices whose element is 0.
indices = [index for index, value in enumerate(values) if value==0] + [len(values)]

# Split the list accordingly
values = [values[indices[i]:indices[i+1]] for i in range(len(indices)-1)]

print(values)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 559]]
```