# What are the differences between bool() and operator.truth()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, performance, boolean

[`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) and [`operator.truth()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truth) both test whether a value is *truthy* or *falsy* and they seem rather similar from the docs, it even says in the `truth()` docs that:

> This is equivalent to using the bool constructor.

However, `truth()` is over twice as fast as `bool()` from a simple test (Python 3.6 timings shown, but 2.7 is similar):

```
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit('bool(1)', number=10000000))
# 2.180289956042543
print(timeit('truth(1)', setup='from operator import truth', number=10000000))
# 0.7202018899843097
```

So what are the differences? Should I use `truth()` instead of `bool()`?

This Q&A arose after extensive comments and discussion with [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909056/creating-a-list-within-a-list-in-python/).

Comment: `timeit('b(1)', 'b=bool')` is noticeably faster than `timeit('bool(1)')` (though still much slower than `truth`). Looking up the global name `bool` affects the results.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, good point, but the time difference is still over double, yes?

Comment: Yes, `truth` is still definitely much faster than `bool` (and, incidentally, slower than `True if ... else False`).

Comment: @khelwood Yep, I guess the `if` statement is highly optimised; use cases for `truth` are where you would parse a keyword argument like `key=bool`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although `bool()` and `operator.truth()` *output* the same result for the major uses cases their *implementation* is actually rather different. `bool()` is a class or type constructor while `truth()` is a narrow optimised regular function.

In practical terms, there are also two differences: 1) `bool()` called with no arguments `return`s `False` while `truth()` requires an argument. 2) `bool()` accepts an `x` key word argument, like `bool(x=1)`, while `truth()` takes no keyword arguments. Both of these add overhead to `bool()` for the regular use cases.

The key word implementation is odd since likely no-one needs it and the name `x` is hardly descriptive. [Issue29695](https://bugs.python.org/issue29695) covers this, and in fact the issue impacts not just `bool()` but other classes like `int()` or `list()`. However, from Python 3.7 onwards these key word arguments will be removed, and speed should improve. Nonetheless, I tested the timings on the latest Python 3.8 branch, and `bool()` is faster than before but still over twice as slow as `truth()`, presumably due to the more generic implementation of `bool()`.

So, if you have a task where speed is of high importance I would recommend using `truth()` over `bool()` if you require a function (for example to parse as a key to `sorted()`). However, as [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) points out, `bool()` can still be faster occasionally, such as `filter(bool, iterable)`, so it is probably best to time your use case to be certain of the best option.

Of course, if you don't need a function and simply want to test if a value is *truthy* or *falsy* you should use the idiomatic `if` or `if not` statements, which are fastest as khelwood and [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) commented.

This Q&A arose after extensive comments and discussion with [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909056/creating-a-list-within-a-list-in-python/).

Comment: If you're microoptimizing to the point where you would care about the cost of `bool`, it'd be better to just use `not not x` instead of `truth(x)`.

Comment: `operator.truth` would only be useful in cases where you need a callback

Comment: @user2357112 well it's half the speed, so maybe sometimes more than microoptimization? but yes, the context this arose in was as a key function (for `itertools.groupby) `

Comment: Also, I think that `filter` might be specifically optimised for the case where you pass `bool` to it.

Comment: @khelwood I see what you mean from a quick timit test, but wouldn't you use `filter(None, iterable)` anyway?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I would use `filter(bool` because I have been persuaded that it is clearer and less special-casey than `filter(None`. It is not impossible that other methods might also optimise for `bool` being passed in as a predicate.

Comment: @khelwood well if you want to go further into this, I would welcome another answer :) I have not looked at all the possible use cases or dug into the actual C implementation myself

Comment: @Chris_Rands My knowledge on this is basically limited to what I have said already. =) Feel free to include any of it in your answer if it seems useful.

Comment: @khelwood: Yeah, [`filter` has a special case for `bool` that makes it treat as equivalent to passing `None`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L593) (instead of actually calling the callback, it just invokes `PyObject_IsTrue` directly). So the exceptional case is one where `bool` isn't invoked at all; if `bool` is actually called, it's always slower than the equivalent `truth`. AFAICT, the only other function that recognizes this case is `itertools.filterfalse`; all other `itertools` (e.g. `takewhile`/`dropwhile`) don't offer such a special case.