# In python why is explicit bool much slower than implicit

Tags: python, performance, python-3.6

Given the following three functions

```py
def v1(a):
    c = 0
    for a_ in a:
        if a_ is not None:
            c += 1
    return c

def v2(a):
    c = 0
    for a_ in a:
        if a_:
            c += 1
    return c

def v3(a):
    c = 0
    for a_ in a:
        if bool(a_):
            c += 1
    return c
```

I get the following performance (I'm using python 3.6 on ubuntu 18.04)

```
values = [random.choice([1, None]) for _ in range(100000)]

%timeit v1(values)
3.35 ms ± 28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit v2(values)
2.83 ms ± 36.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit v3(values)
12.3 ms ± 59.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The similar performance between `v1` and `v2` makes sense, but why is `v3` so much slower given that `v2` is presumably implicitly calling `bool(a_)` too?

Is it simply calling `bool()` from python rather than from c (as I assume `if` does) that's causing the difference in performance?

Comment: Because built-ins... even `x` is faster than `len(x) != 0` or `x != []`. (in some question)

Comment: (what about `c += bool(a)`?)

Comment: I believe `bool()` will actually instantiate a bool class object and then do the check which would lead to a performance hit

Comment: [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45778282/5267751).

Comment: `bool()` is a class or type constructor, it is generic and not optimised for this task, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009870/what-are-the-differences-between-bool-and-operator-truth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a list is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513/how-do-i-check-if-a-list-is-empty)

Comment: @mbrig That is not at all a duplicate just because an answer there touches upon it.

Comment: @mbrig this is not at all the same question. Chris_Rands's linked question is much closer but still not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mainly due to Python's dynamicism and the fact that you have a Python level call.

Using `bool` Python can't directly go and construct a new `bool` object. It has to do look ups to find what exactly is attached to `bool`; then it has check if it is something that can be called, parse its arguments and 
 then call it.

Using a construct such as `if _a`, has a defined meaning. It goes through a specific OPCODE ([`POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ef65f346a5e829a886c075f519e3a49a2ebbde7/Python/ceval.c#L2728) here) and [checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ef65f346a5e829a886c075f519e3a49a2ebbde7/Python/ceval.c#L2740) if the loaded value has a truthy value. Way less hoops to jump through.

`bool` calls the [same function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ef65f346a5e829a886c075f519e3a49a2ebbde7/Objects/boolobject.c#L52) to check if a value supplied is `True` or `False`, it just has a longer trip until it gets there.

Answer (score 2):

`v2` is able to evaluate the "truthiness" of `a_` *in* the interpreter:

```
 >>> dis.dis(v2)
 ...
 11          14 LOAD_FAST                2 (a_)
             16 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10
 ...
```

where `v3` is required to actually call `bool` at the Python level:

```
>>> dis.dis(v3)
...
18          14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bool)
            16 LOAD_FAST                2 (a_)
            18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10
...
```

The function call is what slows `v3` down.