# Casting potential bool to bool in Python, any downsides?

Tags: python, boolean

In my python code I got a few casts of bool() onto variables which I know are likely already Boolean. Are there any downsides to this? (Performance, etc.)

Here's a basic clone of the function I'm using.

```
import re
pattern= "[A-Z]\w[\s]+:"
other_cond= "needs_to_be_in_the_text"
def my_func(to_check: str) -> bool:
    res = re.search(pattern, to_check)
    res2 = other_cond in to_check
    return bool(res), bool(res2) # res2 either None or True
# I need boolean returns because later in my code I add all these  
# returned values to a list and use min(my_list) on it. to see if
# there's any false value in there. min() on list with None values causes exception
```

Comment: your question is too broad, can you provide a sample code? in general explicit casting to `bool` looks noisy and harms readability

Comment: If you don't need to do it, don't do it.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I added an example version of my function.

Comment: Did you mean "truthy"? The result of `re.search` is certainly not a boolean.

Comment: @tobias_k Ups ye I forgot to add the other part in, I check multiple things in my function and all the returned things go into a list which later has min() used on it and a None value causes an exception in there.

Comment: So, after conversion to boolean it will be a list of booleans only on which you can use `min`? It would be more intuitive to use `not all` then. Or would that still be a mixed list?

Comment: Do you mean `not res and not res2`  with `not all`? If so, I'm afraid that won't work very well in my as I have about 15 checks in my actual code - (in the end all the checks are in a list as **guaranteed** booleans and then min() get's used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general casting to `bool()` isn't necessary and you can use the more idiomatic `if:` or `if not:` syntax, but if it is necessary and you want to avoid the overhead of `bool()`, a relatively expensive type constructor, then use a more lightweight approach like `operator.truth`, a specialised function (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009870/what-are-the-differences-between-bool-and-operator-truth)).

Timings from Python 3.6 in Ipython illustrate the `bool()` is relatively slow (this will often be a unnecessary micro-optimisation though):

```
In [1]: import operator

In [2]: %timeit bool('')
130 ns +- 0.528 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit operator.truth('')
87.9 ns +- 0.0777 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit not not ''
25.3 ns +- 0.176 ns per loop (mean +- std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: I refactored my code to use `operator.truth` instead of `bool` casts and it seems to be working just fine - I think I will stick to this as it's even a bit faster than before.
I also tested it for None values specifically and it seems to have been about 30ns faster.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what "a few" is, but generally no.

Of course calling `bool` is slower than not calling `bool`, but it's unlikely that this will be your bottleneck.

---

In theory, casting a variable to `bool` can trigger garbage collection of a large object, e.g.:

```
x = list(range(100000))
x = bool(x)
if x:
    foo()
```

Whether or not you have the second line might affect how soon the `if` body is called: When casting, the original list goes out of scope and gets garbage collected, when not casting, the original list stays in memory.

I'd argue these are edge-cases though.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to comment without seeing example code, but casting to `bool` probably hurts the readability of your code. If statements for example implicitly check the truthiness of the statement, so adding `bool` doesn't give you anything.

```
a = [1,2,3]

if a:
    pass
```

vs. wrapping in bool, which just means more to read.

```
if bool(a):
    pass
```

If you're assigning to new variables, it will mean more things to keep track of and may introduce bugs where the casted and original variables get out of sync.

```
 a = [1,2,3]
 a_bool = bool(a)

 if a_bool:
      pass # will hit

 a = []

 if a_bool:
     pass # will still get here, even though you've updated a
```

If you don't cast, there is nothing to keep track of:

```
a = [1,2,3]
if a:
   pass # will get here

a = []

if a:
    pass  # won't get here.
```

*Truthiness* of variables is commonly exploited in Python, and makes more nice readable code. It's probably better to spend the time getting used to how this works than wrapping things in `bool`.

Comment: Should the `if b:` line be `if a_bool:`?