# How to append list with only True values in Python?

Tags: python

```py
def compact(word):
    holder = []
    for i in word:
        if i is True:
            holder.append(i)
    return holder


print(compact([0, 1, 2, 3, False, ""]))
```

I am a python beginner and this is the code I have written to append the list "holder" with only true values. So the list should contain only 1, 2, 3. However when I run this code the output is only an empty list []. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I am trying to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: you want to check simply `if i`. Your items are integers, which **are not True**. Try running the line `1 is True` in the interpreter and see what you get

Comment: Neither of the objets `1`, `2`, nor `3` `is False`. It sounds like you want *truthy* values, using `is` checks for identity with the singleton `True` object. Just use `if i:` Note, you can sue the built-in `list(filter(None, [0, 1, 2, 3, False, ""]))` for this. When you pass `None` as the predicate, it filters on truthiness

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is there a functional difference for using `None` as the key in `filter` over `bool`?

Comment: @C.Nivs no, there isn't as far as I am aware

Comment: @C.Nivs Actually I believe passing `None` and `bool` are exactly equivalent here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009870/what-are-the-differences-between-bool-and-operator-truth#comment97974258_49009871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `if i:` will do the trick since it returns `False` for `i = 0 or '', or False`

---

**Solution 1: Use `list comprehension`:**

```
input_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, False, ""]
output_list = [i for i in input_list if i]

output_list
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

**Solution 2: If you really need the function, use this:**

```
def compact(word):
    holder = []
    for i in word:
        if i:
            holder.append(i)
    return holder

print(compact([0, 1, 2, 3, False, ""]))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: who is downvoting without reason? Accepted answer with negative score? Great

Answer (score 3):

`int`s are never `True`, but they can be logically `True` - any non-0 int has a logical value of `True`, which is fundamentally different to `int is True`. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650309) for an explanation of the `is` operator.

You can also cut down your code by using list comprehensions:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, False, ""]
compacted = [n for n in lst if n]
```