# Why is `len(l) != 0` faster than `bool(l)` in CPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, cpython

I was doing some experimentation about operations' speed on list. For this I defined two list: `l_short = []` and `l_long = list(range(10**7))`.

The idea is to compare `bool(l)` with `len(l) != 0`

In an `if` contest, the following implementation is faster by a lot `if l: pass` instead of `if len(l) != 0: pass`

But without the if contest I got the following results:

```
%%timeit
len(l_long) != 0
# 59.8 ns ± 0.358 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%%timeit
bool(l_long)
# 63.3 ns ± 0.192 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

The timing of `bool` is slightly longer, why so ?

Here are the bytecodes using `dis` (FYI)

```
dis("len(l_long) != 0")
"""
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (len)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (l_long)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              8 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
"""

dis("bool(l_long)")
"""
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (bool)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (l_long)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
"""
```

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009870/what-are-the-differences-between-bool-and-operator-truth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bool(l_long)` first tries to call `l_long.__bool_()`; however, `list.__bool__` isn't defined. The next step is to call `l_long.__len__() != 0`.

`len(l_long) != 0`, on the other hand, goes straight to `l_long.__len__()`

The time difference you see is essentially the time it takes to catch the `AttributeError` raised by `l_long.__bool__` before calling `l_long.__len__` anyway.

Comment: Thank you very mich for this answer. As a side note, I thought `if l_long: pass` implicitly called `bool(l)`, I am obviously wrong. What does happen in `if l_long: pass` ?

Comment: I think there are other reasons why `bool()` is slow too, read the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909056/creating-a-list-within-a-list-in-python/#comment84833686_48909138

Comment: If you look at the byte code for `if l_long: pass`, you'll see it jumps right to `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` without calling any function at the byte-code level.

Comment: @chepner, I noticed that, so does that mean the interpreter takes care for us of some optimizations underneath ?

Comment: Essentially. When you write `bool(l_long)`, the parser only sees that you are calling something bound to the name `bool`; as a result, the byte-code generator can't assume that `bool` is still bound to the built-in type `bool` (at least not without more work than you want the parser doing), and therefore has to treat it like any other function call. With `if l_long`, on the other hand, there's nothing that could have been overriden at run-time: `l_long` is used in a boolean context, period, so you can skip right to the good stuff buried in the interpreter.