# Using bool as key function in groupby() in Python

Tags: python, list

I am studying list in python and I wonder how to input lists inside a list and saw this method to input multiple list inside a list:

```
 from itertools import groupby
 values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 559]
 print([[0]+list(g) for k, g in groupby(values, bool) if k])
```

I tried to execute this in http://pythontutor.com/ to see the process step-by-step and I don't know what bool is checking if true or false before printing this output: `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 559]]`

link of the code above: [Creating a list within a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909056/creating-a-list-within-a-list-in-python)

Comment: your example is an additional reason why I downvote list comprehensions answers provided to beginners...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to understand such problems is to dissect it.

```
for k,g in groupby(values,bool):
    if k:
        print(*g)
# output
1 2 3 4 5 351
1 2 3 4 5 6 750
1 2 3 4 559
```

```
for k,g in groupby(values,bool):
    if not k:
        print(*g)
# output
0
0
0
```

Python considers `bool(0)` as `False`. So basically, it groups all the numbers between `False` together and it adds them to `[0]` therefore you get your result. `bool(any non 0)` is True.

```
for k,g in groupby(values,bool):
    print(k)
    print(*g)

#output
False
0
True
1 2 3 4 5 351
False
0
True
1 2 3 4 5 6 750
False
0
True
1 2 3 4 559
```

```
for k,g in groupby(values,bool):
    print(k)
    if k:
        print([0]+list(g))
# output
False
True
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 351]
False
True
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 750]
False
True
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 559]
```

***Note***

I might have explained myself loosely, what I meant by it groups what's between `False` together, is because they are `True`.